# Launch character speed incresed when in middle air - unreal4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm working on a 2D game using the preset of the sidescroller in unreal. So, I was trying to add a skill to my character, that was supposed to make him dash in the direction of its mash (left/right). It “worked” using the function launch character from the engine, however I noticed that, when the character is in middle air its launch speed, after activating the skill, is highly increased and I can't figure out why. (I have just started today)

Here's the blueprint:

thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, here is the link: https://prnt.sc/qk843p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already figured it out. I wasn't considering the friction, so when the character is in air the dash is stronger since the friction at that moment is zero. So I just set the value of the friction.